# get request not working in angular 7 using HttpHeaders

Tags: angular

i am using HttpHeaders used to set or unset authorization token but i am getting error like

Argument of type 'OperatorFunction' is not assignable to parameter of type 'OperatorFunction, Response

so how to skip or unskip of better way, because some time token is null

```
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Token ' + token,
      })
    };

    const httpOptions1 = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      })
    };


   let opt;
   if (token) {
     opt = httpOptions
   } else {
    opt = httpOptions1

   }


    return this.http.get<any>(this.mURL , opt)
      .pipe(map((response: Response) => {
        return response;
      }), catchError((error: Response) => {
        return throwError(error.status);
      }));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the best solution to create an interceptor : 
create a new file :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpInterceptor, HttpHandler, HttpRequest, HttpEvent, HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any> , next: HttpHandler ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token'); // or from wherever you like to get your token 
    if (token) {
      req = req.clone({
        headers : req.headers.set('authorization', 'Bearer ' + token)
      });
      req = req.clone({
        headers  : req.headers.set('Accept', 'application/json, text/plain, */*') // this for accepting the most of body requests 
      });
      return next.handle(req).pipe(
        map((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
          if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
           console.log('event --->>', event); // you can remove that line in production build stage 
          }
          return event;
        }
      ));
    } else {
      return next.handle(req);
    }
  }
}
```

and your interceptor into you app.module.ts  providers

```
providers:[
   {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass : AuthInterceptor,
      multi: true
    }]
```

it will add the token in every request you will make

Comment: i think this procedure is best way